# Regular Expression how to match IP and port after a few garbage data

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to extract the IP and Port from html text.

The data looks like this

`177.93.79.34\n<!--\n<img src='images/proxy/3537536.gif' border='0' hspace='0' vspace='0' width='140' height='14' alt='View this Proxy details'/>\n-->\n</a></td>\n\t<td><a href='/proxy-4145-Socks4--ssl.htm' title='Select proxies with port number 4145'>4145`

My regular expression pattern looks like this.

`MatchCollection Match = Regex.Matches(source, @"\b(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}\b\s\S.*Select proxies with port number ([0-9]+)");`

I also try this
`\b(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}\b[\s\S].*Select proxies with port number ([0-9]+)`

But I get 0 results.. if I take off `\b\s\S.*Select proxies with port number ([0-9]+)` it finds all the IP addressses great.. but the information is useless without the port data how would I both in 1 regular expression match.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SSpoke,

If you're trying to keep things as close to your original Regex as possible, simply replacing `[\s\S].*`  with `[\s\S]*` in the middle takes care of it. ([Demo](https://regex101.com/r/7Es7kA/3))

Generally, however, it's best to throw your different parts of interest into capture groups, like such:

```
(\b(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}\b)([\s\S]*?Select proxies with port number)\s([0-9]+)
```

([Demo](https://regex101.com/r/7Es7kA/2))

The main issue (as I see it) involves this portion of your expression: `[\s\S].*`
That section is supposed to deal will all of the junk in between the IP and the Port number, but what it really says is, find one character that is either a `\s` or not a `\S` (which is any character) followed by any character ***except*** a new line character 0 to unlimited times (`.*`). Although the text pasted into your original question was a single line, the "source" in your C# code (the HTML) was not. To solve the problem, you just need to change the expression to `[\s\S]*` which will match any character ***including*** newline characters, 0 to unlimited times.

Comment: Tried it, 0 matches.. yup pretty strange heh

Comment: Even tried `RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace` does nothing.. i think its some kind of `\n` or something that breaks it.

Comment: @SSpoke, I believe I've found the problem. I've updated my post. Give that Regex a try.

Comment: What's the problem? Could you share as I'm curious too :D @JimSimson

Comment: @SSpoke, I'm going to update my post to explain what was going on. Stand by.

Comment: @JimSimson you got a paypal account i'll send you something for your help

Comment: @SSpoke, HaHa! Helping out is it's own reword. Thanks though!

Comment: @JimSimson haha you are good man, ahh everything has a price, we all gotta eat at the end of the day, either way greatly apperiate your help saved me alot of headaches, maybe one day I will return the favor if we meet again.  P.S. I think that `\s` near the port detection also played a role in this I completely missed that.

Comment: @SSpoke, Thanks man. Comments like yours make it all worthwhile. Good luck with the rest of your project!

Answer (score 2):

If the HTML format is certain, maybe this regex can help (in JavaScript)

`const regex = /((?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}).+Select proxies with port number.+?([0-9]{4})/gm` with the results being captured in two groups.

Comment: Thank you, but it doesn't work in C# https://i.imgur.com/3in2763.png and results: https://i.imgur.com/zcwyudY.png  I dont think I can use the `/gm` in C#

Comment: Removing `/` and `/gm` and adding `RegexOptions.SingleLine` kinda works but only matches 1 match out of the 10 on the site. https://i.imgur.com/Oo4PljJ.png

Comment: @SSpoke I see, seems to be a C# specific issue. `string pattern = @"((?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}).+Select proxies with port number.+?([0-9]{4})";` should at least help you find the first match in the string (as it's not greedy match). If you want to match all outputs, maybe you can try to use a loop?

Comment: Nope the SingleLine approach is useless.. it only matches the first occurrence then stops, don't know how I would loop it I gotta trim the source data to remove all the old data or something. I guess i'll do it as my last resort.